# Show full file name in fine-uploader

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Is it possible to show the full file name in Fine Uploader during the upload? 
I haven't been able to find an option for that in the [documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com).

Comment: Can you clarify what a "full file name" is?

Comment: I mean the file name without the path. If for example the upload folder is in /httpdocs/upload/ (ftp server) and the file being uploaded is my_uploaded_file_with_a_long_name_including_custom_data.zip, i would like to have "my_uploaded_file_with_a_long_name_including_custom_data.zip" shown during the upload instead of "my_uploaded_fi...tom_data.zip". I hope that is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, Fine Uploader, by default, shortens the displayed file name to 33 characters.  You can override this behavior by contributing your own `formatFileName` function.  This is described in the [Fine Uploader Basic options section](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/options/fineuploaderbasic.html#fineuploaderbasic-mode-options).

For example, this will ensure the filename is no longer shortened:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: '/my/endpoint'
    },
    formatFileName: function(filename) {
        return filename;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I had missed that.